rxjs Cancel previous http request on new subscription call
I am trying to use a slightly altered version of this with angular:
Observables : Cancel previous http request on new subscription call
but it does not work.
<input id="searchbox" value="{{ searchTerm$ | async }}" #searchBox type="text" (input)="search(searchBox.value)">

The .ts
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchTerms.pipe(
        tap((term: string) => this.store.dispatch(new SearchForTermAction(term))),
    ).subscribe();
}

search(term: string): void {
    if (term.length >= 2) {
      this.searchTerms.next(term);
    }
}

and in the state
@Action(SearchForTermAction)
async searchForTerm(ctx: StateContext<SearchStateModel>, action: SearchForTermAction) {
    const currentState = ctx.getState();
    of(action.searchTerm).pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        // ignore new term if same as previous term
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(term => this.service.searchTerm(term)),
        ).subscribe(res => {
          console.log("result gotten");
          ctx.setState({
            searchResults: res,
            loading: false,
          });
        });
      }

However, "result gotten" will be printed multiple times when I put in a search term. Where is my mistake?

I think you might have to move the debounce and distinct until changed before you dispatch the action, on the ngOnInit

By using of you are creating a new observable that emits a single value every time the action is called, so the debounceTime and distinctUntilChanged operators do not have a previous values to compare against. So instead you should attach those operators to the Subject's continuous value stream.
To cancel the request when a new value arrives, typically you'd use the switchMap operator. However since you're using ngxs you will instead need the cancelUncompleted option in the action decorator. See https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/cancellation
In the component:
ngOnInit() {
  this.searchTerms
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term: string) => this.store.dispatch(new SearchForTermAction(term)))
    )
    .subscribe();
}

In the state:
@Action(SearchForTermAction, { cancelUncompleted: true })
searchForTerm(ctx: StateContext<SearchStateModel>, action: SearchForTermAction) {
  return this.service.searchTerm(action.searchTerm).pipe(
    tap(res => {
      console.log('result gotten');
      ctx.setState({
        searchResults: res,
        loading: false
      });
    })
  );
}

PS: please add the ngxs tag since it's more related to that library than rxjs.
